# Printing an ArrayList to a JTextField via a JButton

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jbutton, jtextfield

I have created a library Class of which has an ArrayList of Books called booklist.

```
public class Library {
    
    //Fields
    String libraryName;
    ArrayList<Book> booklist;

    //Constructor
    public Library() {
        this.libraryName = "Mt Baker";
    }

    public Library(String libraryName) {
        this.libraryName = libraryName;
        this.booklist = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

I have created a print method which works great to print the ArrayList to console.

```
public void printBooks() {
        for (Book s : booklist)
            System.out.println("Title: \t" + s.getTitle() + "\t\tAuthor: " + s.getAuthor() +
            "\tYear: " + s.getYear() + "\tISBN :" + s.getISBN());
    }
```

I cannot work out how to code the actionPerformed that would allow this method to print the ArrayList into the JTextArea. I have tried various iterations:-

```
String op = evt.getActionCommand();
            Library x = new Library();
            ArrayList <Book> y = new ArrayList<>();

if (op.equals("Show Library")) {
                GUI.this.libraryResult.setText(y.printBooks().toString());
            }
```

libraryResult is the JTextField, "Show Library" the JButton Listener Event.

Other advice on this site recommends use of append and toString, but I have not managed to make them work. Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: does it work for you (my answer)?

Comment: *Other advice on this site recommends use of append* - yes you would use the `append(..)` method of the JTextArea to add text as you iterate through the ArrayList. However, forget about the ArrayList. First create a simple GUI with a JFrame a JTextArea and a JButton and an Array with a few strings of text. Learn how to write an ActionListener for the button to add the text from the Array to the text area. Once you understand that basic concept it will be each replace the Array with the ArrayList. Using this approach you can post your [mre] if you have problems.

Comment: No, I'm still trying. This line doesn't work:

Comment: String text = getAsString();

The getAsString() method just shows up as red and says "Cannot resolve method 'getAsString' in 'event'. I figured it needed applying to the Library, so I put x.getAsString which removes the error over the method, but it then returns a null event when I press the JButton, saying that the ArrayList is empty.

Comment: *"This line doesn't work:"* What line? Tip: Add @IntoVoid (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: what exactly does not work. The action listener, or the getAsString method (in my answer). Or the setting of the text. You can find out using a debugger e.g. in IntelliJ

Comment: @IntoVoid Thank you for following up. The bad was mine, your code does work, I had it referring to an unpopulated ArrrayList which was why I was getting a null error.

FWIW I also found another solution:-

libraryResult.setText(libraryResult.getText() + book.getTitle())

Answer (score 1):

```
GUI.this.yourButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String text = getAsString();
        GUI.this.libraryResult.setText(text);
    }
});

...

// Put this method somewhere else (where there is still access to your booklist)
public String getAsString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Book s : booklist) {
        sb.append("Title: \t" + s.getTitle() + "\t\tAuthor: " + s.getAuthor() + "\tYear: " + s.getYear() + "\tISBN :" + s.getISBN());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you have under your current class GUI, but if you change 'GUI.this.yourButton' and 'GUI.this.libraryResult' to whatever you need, it should work